# VSTS Sprint Capacity - Unable to select Activity

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Since the recent UI update (June 2018) on Visual Studio Team Services, I've not been able to select activities for team members in the sprint capacity screen; all that's showing up is "Unassigned":

[image]

I'd expect this select list to be populated as per the Activity select list on the Task work item screen:

[image]

I've had a good look through both Project Settings and Admin Settings but can't find anywhere this is configured.

It's evident that the activity types exist because as shown above, they can be selected at the work item level, just not in the capacity screen.

**How can I get the dropdown to populate correctly? Is this a bug?**

Comment: Did you see any error message in the Develop Console if you press F12?

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT I'm no longer getting the described behaviour after clearing cookies and cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested on my side, everything works as expected. Just try to clean the caches and try it again, or try with other browsers or clients.

More information please see [Set your team's capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scrum/set-capacity?view=vsts&tabs=vertical)

> **Prerequisites**
>
> - You must connect to a team project. If you don't have a team project    yet, create one in VSTS.
> - You must be a member of the Contributors group or be granted    **[Stakeholder access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/security/get-started-stakeholder?view=vsts)** to add or modify work items. Or, you must have    your View work items in this node, and your Edit work items in
>     this    node permissions set to Allow.
> - If you haven't been added to a team project or team, get added now.    To learn more, see Set permissions and access for work tracking.
>
> To learn more, see [Set permissions and access for work tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=vsts).

[image]